# Will adding more RAM to my system speed up rendering?

Tags: after-effects, hardware, adobe-media-encoder, aerender

When I render any AE composition, through AE or Media Encoder it seems to take a long time. I want to increase my render times.

I have noticed that my CPU usage seems to fluctuate consistantly where as my RAM consistanly stays around 70% usage.
[image: Fluctuating CPU]

Is there any way that I increase the amount of CPU and RAM AE uses to speed up the render time?

Also would adding more RAM to my system actually speed up render times?

[image]

Thanks in advanced

EDIT: I am rendering the save to a different hard drive from the one the render is running from. Both are internal disk drives.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the dips in CPU usage are where the source files are being pulled off disk, or written to disk. You could speed things up in this case by using the command line renderer and having a couple of instances going, to soak up the spare cycles. But the more instances you have, the more memory you'll need, so the answer might be yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your external drive is a spinning disk, and your internal drive is an SSD, you may find it faster to host the project and render everything on the internal drive.

This is what I do - the problem is keeping enough available space on the drive as SSDs are expensive and small.

Answer (score 0):

Add more RAM and render to your SDD drive and your renders should go a bit faster.